# Python Requests Get not pulling webpage

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a list of UPC code and I am trying to write a script to pull information about them form https://www.barcodelookup.com but the request is returning only the html tags but none of the information I want.
Here is a sample of my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://www.barcodelookup.com/075610166101')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
bsoup = soup.prettify()
with open('output1.html', 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(bsoup))

with open('output.html', 'w')as file:
    file.write(str(page.text))
```

sample outpout.html1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en-US">
 <!--<![endif]-->
 <head>
  <title>
   Attention Required! | Cloudflare
  </title>
  <meta id="captcha-bypass" name="captcha-bypass"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
  <meta content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
  <meta content="noindex, nofollow" name="robots"/>
  <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
  <link href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.css" id="cf_styles-css" media="screen,projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" id='cf_styles-ie-css' href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" /><![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css">
   body{margin:0;padding:0}
  </style>
  <!--[if gte IE 10]><!-->
  <script src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/zepto.min.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <!--[if gte IE 10]><!-->
  <script src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/cf.common.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css">
   #cf-wrapper #spinner {width:69px; margin:  auto;}
  #cf-wrapper #cf-please-wait{text-align:center}
  .attribution {margin-top: 32px;}
  .bubbles { background-color: #f58220; width:20px; height: 20px; margin:2px; border-radius:100%; display:inline-block; }
  #cf-wrapper #challenge-form { padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:25px; }
  #cf-hcaptcha-container { text-align:center;}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="cf-wrapper">
   <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error" data-translate="enable_cookies" id="cookie-alert">
    Please enable cookies.
   </div>
   <div class="cf-error-details-wrapper" id="cf-error-details">
    <div class="cf-wrapper cf-header cf-error-overview">
     <h1 data-translate="challenge_headline">
      One more step
     </h1>
     <h2 class="cf-subheadline">
      <span data-translate="complete_sec_check">
       Please complete the security check to access
      </span>
      www.barcodelookup.com
     </h2>
    </div>
```

sample outpou1.html:

```
<div class="cf-section cf-highlight cf-captcha-container">
     <div class="cf-wrapper">
      <div class="cf-columns two">
       <div class="cf-column">
        <div class="cf-highlight-inverse cf-form-stacked">
         <form action="/075610166101?__cf_chl_captcha_tk__=10080e641441171d59b24657ed37a7381be4a368-1595778921-0-AS91JaY_1ozqjwuL0cLJj39tDQ8tO-5t6vMnZ4LFD6V9L_k_jFw1qb6NW_KOPGyf53pazgUHKpjsBF0oCu3pWy-n1rks1eGTzPNdPJvDUgly5EfmCU2hfkPgF0u9Mmb0jAt0uNra1wy-xDgG87ZgWd3KvYSj1Jre0DtwvkXITbLAaAdSg5UeBhw4DDEuCxFILAwhLTU3YHEm9F1CbC7cqA-U05kTDiOIBnZngHGBrnOWB9LYl6asezmwfpuzNZTovixMVE8BBKVfIf1gJjllYh7626I1abfYw38uuoIy0viPuN_CtjB8JoBbs2qrix4gXW6PGu9EA5ZPhBw-IQ8csPLN-a0WFRqB3Il-Hz6M6z9Wdb-OHUKOjX37n_fBuQarqU34cgbG4CNpD_7cdn_NUrlJ6xsRZiFV13V2q4zBS4XpPwabA_unBIjziYgIiB-y9hwndtV08bMXxtoSqtNxxev3fNnL_cQ" class="challenge-form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="challenge-form" method="POST">
          <input name="r" type="hidden" value="33260f1c9e17bb57e0d89a1d21e050da58f9c0a0-1595778921-0-Ad2sk2X3qN2WwWLekQkZpeJCOg0H0bI9CHDtAranzrOjQHfchnqyW9dHD3S6CpbKRRrV/9pFNY+jLG7XUks78zi0PsNBHSNwDV4ad2liittfYU5X73GgFmyN3COYAQomUPoPxw+YPyMTRPrR0P6qFUh92fhmLMbivztY8iwFFTppCHO1Kx8Ax+4orJWgb31sJpRrtuasqpgFs9qCAhBgBKzue/BginjozYpNbGDlrdjnWnh+b+SxL+HWxzkFLwxoIWDJ6dMHaZSp/zvBptO5cgBTpPupAYNvcB2O3YGapY0UefpxmhXntG50yXyrQmobqrh4rjuyXgDup3HO8ETKUwnZ37f4NN0LuYA2k9nveVh0j9hqy/P09wbQE8AChLs2/u2uqpTcGyPSpbTOyNo1FjfD+BpE6KqQsL8l9hOtHuHviayTngoqOrOMW6"/>
          <input name="cf_captcha_kind" type="hidden" value="h"/>
          <input name="vc" type="hidden" value=""/>
          <script async="" data-ray="5b8f4df52fe3741d"
```

I am trying to post both output file to show the returned information but the system won't let me.

Comment: Why don't you use their [API](https://www.barcodelookup.com/api-documentation)?

Comment: I saw the option but I don't really know how to use it.

Comment: also I have to subscribe to use it. I am doing a little project for myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websites usually put some security mechanisms in order to avoid getting **scraped**. The most basic check is serving content based on a user-agent so if a requesting client is not sharing any user-agent information it will be considered as an unsupported browser or some bot/script. So, just adding a user-agent header parameter (mimicking Google Chrome) is allowing us to get content from this site.

Here is your updated script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'
}
page = requests.get('https://www.barcodelookup.com/075610166101', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
bsoup = soup.prettify()
with open('output1.html', 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(bsoup))

with open('output.html', 'w')as file:
    file.write(str(page.text))
```